# Getting file owner on network share via dir

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that does several things, and among them is:

`dir "\\network_share\directory" /Q /A:-D /S > output.txt`

The file then writes out lines like this:

`01/01/2012  01:01 PM           100,000 DOMAIN\user       filename.doc`

However, when I ran the same script while VPN'ed in, the results were as follows:

`01/01/2012  01:01 PM           100,000 . . .       filename.doc`

Odd thing is that if I go to that folder in Windows Explorer, and enable the Owner column, I can see the data just fine.

What can be causing this behavior and how do I correct it to work over VPN?

Comment: Are the two DIR commands being run from the same machine? If not, what OS's are the two machines running?

Comment: Tried from the same machine (Windows 7), and tried from a virtual XP. I can't seem to find any documentation on what ". . ." means in response to /Q.